# Muliple Joins sum values based on two different critiea with sort

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that has 4 tables.

```
Table 1 - "company" table with company_id as the key
Table 2 - "users" table with the user_id as the key
Table 3 - "teams" table that references the company_id and the user_id (So that user can belong to multiple teams.
Table 4 - "points" table that references the company_id, the user_id, points_earned (Numeric value of points given), exchange_dte (0 - if the user has not used the points, otherwise a unixtime value)
```

Given a known company_id, I am trying to call all users that belong to that "team" and show their total points and their un-exchanged points. The following MySQL will only give the first user on company's #1 team.  There are currently 5 users in the database all with a number of points earned, some exchanged, some not.

```
SELECT 
users.user_id AS u_id, 
SUM(points.points_earned) AS ttl_points,
SUM(case when exchange_dte = '0' then points.points_earned else 0 end) AS unused_points
FROM users
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.user_id = users.user_id
INNER JOIN points ON points.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE (teams.company_id = '1' AND points.company_id = '1' AND users.user_active = '1');
```

So then I tried to add the user_id to the Sum calls.  And end up with the same thing.

```
SELECT
users.user_id AS u_id, 
SUM(case when points.user_id = users.user_id then points.points_earned else 0 end) AS ttl_points,
SUM(case when points.exchange_dte = '0' AND points.user_id = users.user_id then points.points_earned else 0 end) AS unused_points
FROM users
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.user_id = users.user_id
INNER JOIN points ON points.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE (teams.company_id = '1' AND points.company_id = '1' AND users.user_active = '1')
ORDER BY ttl_points;
```

The interesting thing is,  the point totals for the first user appear to be all the points in the database, even though they have a user_id and company_id associated with them

Thoughts?

Comment: @user1330742 Ok, I didn't know you needed privileges to edit your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do a SUM without using GROUP BY: not sure if it will work for you but try this adding a `GROUP BY users.user_id` after the end of the query and see if that helps you out.

```
SELECT
users.user_id AS u_id, 
SUM(case when points.user_id = users.user_id then points.points_earned else 0 end) AS ttl_points,
SUM(case when points.exchange_dte = '0' AND points.user_id = users.user_id then points.points_earned else 0 end) AS unused_points
FROM users
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.user_id = users.user_id
INNER JOIN points ON points.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE (teams.company_id = '1' AND points.company_id = '1' AND users.user_active = '1') GROUP BY users.user_id
ORDER BY ttl_points;
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it perfectly.  This is my first time experimenting with SUM inside a MySQL Statement.  Thank you for also explaining what I was missing.

Comment: Glad it helped. Aggregation is always confusing the first couple of times you run across it, and I've definitely been bitten by that bug before.

Comment: One final question.  If a user does not have any points accumulated in the database they are not showing up.

Comment: You might want to replace the `INNER JOIN` on the points table with a `LEFT JOIN`: try that and see if it works. Not sure how well it will work though.

Comment: Gives me the same result.  The user is actually being listed, because when looping the results with php I get a blank row, just not getting the user_id.  I can put in checks to display "0" for both sets of points.

Comment: Odd. Try a LEFT JOIN on both?

Comment: Yes, changed both to LEFT JOIN.  Still not getting the User_id